# Lattice: multiple plots in one window?

Tags: r, lattice

I'm trying to put multiple lattice plots in one window using `levelplot` by setting `par(mfrow=c(2,1))` but it seems to be ignoring this.

Is there a particular function for setting multiple plots in `lattice`?

Comment: The `lattice` plots do not use the `par` settings in general. They have their own set of settings from Grid graphics. See `?trellis.par.get` for an explanation.

Answer (score 77):

The 'lattice' package is built on the grid package and attaches its namespace when 'lattice' loaded. However, in order to use the `grid.layout` function, you need to explicitly `load()` pkg::grid. The other alternative, that is probably easier, is the `grid.arrange` function in pkg::gridExtra:

```
 install.packages("gridExtra")
 require(gridExtra) # also loads grid
 require(lattice)
 x <- seq(pi/4, 5 * pi, length.out = 100)
 y <- seq(pi/4, 5 * pi, length.out = 100)
 r <- as.vector(sqrt(outer(x^2, y^2, "+")))

 grid <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)
 grid$z <- cos(r^2) * exp(-r/(pi^3))
 plot1 <- levelplot(z~x*y, grid, cuts = 50, scales=list(log="e"), xlab="",
           ylab="", main="Weird Function", sub="with log scales",
           colorkey = FALSE, region = TRUE)

 plot2 <- levelplot(z~x*y, grid, cuts = 50, scales=list(log="e"), xlab="",
           ylab="", main="Weird Function", sub="with log scales",
           colorkey = FALSE, region = TRUE)
 grid.arrange(plot1,plot2, ncol=2)
```

[image]

Comment: [Here](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html) you can find neat examples.

Comment: @Masoud: That page only uses base graphics. The question was about lattice graphics.

Comment: @42- Sorry I meant to leave that comment for another question while I was reading your answer. You're right.

Answer (score 42):

The *Lattice* Package often (but not always) ignores the *par* command, so i just avoid using it when plotting w/ *Lattice*.

To place multiple lattice plots on a single page:

- ***create*** (but don't plot) the lattice/trellis ***plot objects***, then
- call ***print*** once for each plot
- for each *print* call, pass in arguments for (i) the *plot*; (ii)
  ***more***, set to *TRUE*, and which is only passed in for the initial call to *print*, and (iii) ***pos***, which gives the position of each plot on the page specified as x-y coordinate pairs for the plot's lower left-hand corner and upper right-hand
  corner, respectively--ie, a vector with four numbers.

much easier to show than to tell:

```
data(AirPassengers)     # a dataset supplied with base R
AP = AirPassengers      # re-bind to save some typing

# split the AP data set into two pieces 
# so that we have unique data for each of the two plots
w1 = window(AP, start=c(1949, 1), end=c(1952, 1))
w2 = window(AP, start=c(1952, 1), end=c(1960, 12))

px1 = xyplot(w1)
px2 = xyplot(w2)

# arrange the two plots vertically
print(px1, position=c(0, .6, 1, 1), more=TRUE)
print(px2, position=c(0, 0, 1, .4))
```

Comment: See also the `split` argument to `?print.trellis` and section 5.8 of Murrell's "R graphics" http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=78P4zntHHVQC

Comment: If there are common axes the `c.trellis` shortcut in the `latticeExtra` package is also useful.

Answer (score 15):

This is simple to do once you read `?print.trellis`. Of particular interest is the `split` parameter. It may seem complicated at first sight, but it's quite straightforward once you understand what it means. From the documentation:

> split: a vector of 4 integers, c(x,y,nx,ny), that says to position the current plot at the x,y position in a regular array of nx by ny plots. (Note: this has origin at top left)

You can see a couple of implementations on `example(print.trellis)`, but here's one that I prefer:

```
library(lattice)

# Data
w <- as.matrix(dist(Loblolly))
x <- as.matrix(dist(HairEyeColor))
y <- as.matrix(dist(rock))
z <- as.matrix(dist(women))

# Plot assignments
pw <- levelplot(w, scales = list(draw = FALSE))  # "scales..." removes axes
px <- levelplot(x, scales = list(draw = FALSE))
py <- levelplot(y, scales = list(draw = FALSE))
pz <- levelplot(z, scales = list(draw = FALSE))

# Plot prints
print(pw, split = c(1, 1, 2, 2), more = TRUE)
print(px, split = c(2, 1, 2, 2), more = TRUE)
print(py, split = c(1, 2, 2, 2), more = TRUE)
print(pz, split = c(2, 2, 2, 2), more = FALSE)  # more = FALSE is redundant
```

The code above gives you this figure:
[image: levelplots]

As you can see, `split` takes four parameters. The *last two* refer to the size of your frame (similar to what `mfrow` does), whereas the *first two* parameters position your plot into the `nx` by `ny` frame.