# R: common legend for multiple plots with different scales

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 6 ggplots which I align  with the arrange.grid into 3 rows. I want to create a common legend for all the plots. I read this answer from this question which explained things in a very nice way.

[Add a common Legend for combined ggplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649473/add-a-common-legend-for-combined-ggplots)

but the problem is that the idea mentioned here will take the legend of p1.

in my case, the legend in each plot has a different scale.

```
i.e. p1 : 0.6 to 0.8
i.e. p2 : 1.6 to 2.2
```

hence this answer does not work in my case.

How can i make 1 legend that contain the scale limits of all the 6 plots.

Comment: Why don't you set the limits on all the scales to the same values?  Also, if you make your example reproducible you'll get more help.

Comment: Look at the documentation for `?facet_grid(...)`. This will create a consolidated legend and arrange the plots for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a workaround, which is to create a new plot which contains all the scales from the all the other plots, and use this one as the custom legend.

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example of your proposed solution?