# How to add a shared x-axis and legend to ggplot (arrangegrob) and avoid different sized figures?

Tags: r, ggplot2, size, legend

[image]

I,m trying to get these figures together in one figure, but I would like to have a shared x-axis below all 3, without the last figure to have a different size than the other 2. Similar for the middle figure with the legend, I would like the legend to be outide the 6 figure, without affecting the size of one of the figures.
I use arrangeGrob(plot1, plot2, ...., plot6) right now.

If anyone has a sollution, please let me know.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `ggplot::facet_grid` to share the axis and `gridExtra::grid.arrange` to plot them side by side

```
data(mtcars)
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(vs), y = mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(cyl~.)

# Hope that i understood your question about the legend correctly

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = gear, y = mpg, col = factor(vs))) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(cyl~.)

grid.arrange(p1,p2, nrow=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering. This is sort of what I mean, but I forgot to mention that my data.table is a little more complicated. The three graphs each have their own column with their data points, not one shared column like cyl.

Should I put all the results below eachother and give them another factor (for instance cyl 4,6,8) to be able to do this?

Comment: have a look at `reshape2::melt` to arrange the data accodringly

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is how far I got this time. The figure are indeed similar within each row. However, I would like all the six graphs to be the same size, but it is difficult due to fact that the left 3 need a legend and "long" x-axis labels. The right panel is just the way I would like it for both panels and with that the x-labels and legend outside of the box.

For example the graph below with the legend (pasted on the right side) and x-labels added to it, without changing the figures size or at least cause no differences between figure sizes [image]

Comment: Have a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649473/add-a-common-legend-for-combined-ggplots