# Common legend for a grid plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

In this reproducible example grid plot, 3 plots have 3 fill colours, and z displays with the "col" blue, but in the fourth plot there is only 1 "col", so z displays as red.

I want to show only one common legend (which I can do), **but I want z to be blue in all four plots.**. Is there a simple way to do that?

[image]

```
#---------------------
# Reproducible example
#---------------------
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
d0 <- read_csv("x, y, col\na,2,x\nb,2,y\nc,1,z")
d1 <- read_csv("x, y, col\na,2,x\nb,2,y\nc,1,z")
d2 <- read_csv("x, y, col\na,2,x\nb,2,y\nc,1,z")
d3 <- read_csv("x, y, col\na,2,z\nb,2,z\nc,1,z")
p0 <- ggplot(d0) + geom_col(mapping = aes(x, y, fill = col))
p1 <- ggplot(d1) + geom_col(mapping = aes(x, y, fill = col))
p2 <- ggplot(d2) + geom_col(mapping = aes(x, y, fill = col))
p3 <- ggplot(d3) + geom_col(mapping = aes(x, y, fill = col))
grid.arrange(p0, arrangeGrob(p1,p2,p3, ncol=3), ncol=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved using gtable to extract the legend and reversing the levels of `col` factor:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(gtable)
d0 <- read_csv("x, y, col\na,2,x\nb,2,y\nc,1,z")
d1 <- read_csv("x, y, col\na,2,x\nb,2,y\nc,1,z")
d2 <- read_csv("x, y, col\na,2,x\nb,2,y\nc,1,z")
d3 <- read_csv("x, y, col\na,2,z\nb,2,z\nc,1,z")

d0 %>% 
  mutate(col = factor(col, levels = c("z", "y", "x"))) %>% 
  ggplot() + geom_col(mapping = aes(x, y, fill = col)) -> p0

d1 %>%
  mutate(col = factor(col, levels = c("z", "y", "x"))) %>% 
  ggplot() + geom_col(mapping = aes(x, y, fill = col))+
  theme(legend.position="bottom") -> p1

d2 %>%
  mutate(col = factor(col, levels = c("z", "y", "x"))) %>% 
  ggplot() + geom_col(mapping = aes(x, y, fill = col)) -> p2

d3 %>%
  ggplot() + geom_col(mapping = aes(x, y, fill = col)) -> p3

legend = gtable_filter(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1)), "guide-box")

grid.arrange(p0 + theme(legend.position="none"), 
             arrangeGrob(p1 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                         p2 + theme(legend.position="none"), 
                         p3 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                         nrow = 1),
             legend,
             heights=c(1.1, 1.1, 0.1),
             nrow = 3)
```

[image]

Another approach is to use  `scale_fill_manual` in every plot without changing the factor levels.

example:

```
p0 + scale_fill_manual(values = c("x" = "red", "z" = "black", "y" = "green"))
```

[image]

so with your original data and legend extracted:

```
d0 <- read_csv("x, y, col\na,2,x\nb,2,y\nc,1,z")
d1 <- read_csv("x, y, col\na,2,x\nb,2,y\nc,1,z")
d2 <- read_csv("x, y, col\na,2,x\nb,2,y\nc,1,z")
d3 <- read_csv("x, y, col\na,2,z\nb,2,z\nc,1,z")
p0 <- ggplot(d0) + geom_col(mapping = aes(x, y, fill = col))
p1 <- ggplot(d1) + geom_col(mapping = aes(x, y, fill = col))
p2 <- ggplot(d2) + geom_col(mapping = aes(x, y, fill = col))
p3 <- ggplot(d3) + geom_col(mapping = aes(x, y, fill = col))
legend = gtable_filter(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1 + theme(legend.position="bottom"))), "guide-box")

grid.arrange(p0 + theme(legend.position="none"), 
             arrangeGrob(p1 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                         p2 + theme(legend.position="none"), 
                         p3 + theme(legend.position="none") +
                           scale_fill_manual(values = c("z" = "#619CFF")),
                         nrow = 1),
             legend,
             heights=c(1.1, 1.1, 0.1),
             nrow = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the great ideas.  For the moment, I've gone with scale_fill_manual as my code, like the example, has only 3 legend values.  I'll explore the other option when In have more time.

Comment: This drives me crazy, why is the legend not exactly centered in the next row??

Comment: @wolfsatthedoor this is a rather outdated answer, there are many packages which can be used to get a shared legend - see answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649473/add-a-common-legend-for-combined-ggplots

Answer (score 6):

Finally a time for my ggplot2 package to shine!

Use `grid_arrange_shared_legend` which was incorporated in the package `lemon` (https://cran.r-project.org/package=lemon). There's an example in the [Working with legends](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lemon/vignettes/legends.html) vignette.

The result could be like this:
[image: Example from vignette]

But... it didn't work for your example, so I've updated the package. You'll need to install the devel-version from github:

```
library(devtools)
install_github('stefanedwards/lemon', ref='e05337a')
```

which would give you the following

```
library(lemon)
# your code to create p0 - p4
nt <- theme(legend.position='none')
grid_arrange_shared_legend(p0, arrangeGrob(p1+nt,p2+nt,p3+nt, ncol=3), ncol=1, nrow=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  This package looks interesting, and I'll give it a try when I have more time.  As a short-term solution for the example I have, I've used scale_fill_manual.