# R 'ggplot2' Arranging common and unique legends with multiple (gridded) plot objects.

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend

**edit - reproducible example included below**

I have been using [this function](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/wiki/Share-a-legend-between-two-ggplot2-graphs) with the ggplot2 package to [Add a common Legend for combined ggplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649473/add-a-common-legend-for-combined-ggplots) which works perfecty when each plot has only 1 type of legend e.g. for `...,color =, ...`.

However, I am trying to arrange multiple plots which share a common legend but each has an additional unique legend e.g.:

```
  ggplot(df1, aes(x=Site, y=RESULT, color=Position , shape=DETNAME)) +
        geom_point(size=5) + ylab ("concentration (mg/L)") +
        labs (shape = "Determinand")
```

which produces :

[image]

I have 3x these where the Position legend is shared but the Determinand legends are unique.

So I want to know if there is an additional argument I can pass to `grid_arrange_shared_legend()` which will preserve the Determinand legends (`shape = DETNAME`) i.e. plotting them above each plot on the grid using something like `legend.position = "top"` but having a common legend for Position (`color = position`) ?

I know I can add `+ guides(shape = FALSE )` to each plot object and then use `grid_arrange_shared_legend()` which gives me the shared Position legend, but I want to achieve something like this but with a unique Determinand legend for each plot: 
[image]

Or could any one advise which part of the source code for the `grid_arrange_shared_legend()` function needs editing to perform this?

**edit - reproducible example**

```
  library (ggplot2)
  library(gridExtra)
  library (grid)

   # two ggplot plot objects with multiple legends 1 common legend and 2 unique

  p1<- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=price, y= depth, color= clarity , shape= cut )) +
    geom_point(size=5) + labs (shape = "unique legend", color = "common legend")

  p2 <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=price, y= depth, color= clarity , shape= color )) +
 geom_point(size=5) + labs (shape = "unique legend", color = "common legend")

   # shared legend function

  grid_arrange_shared_legend <- function(..., ncol = length(list(...)), nrow     = 1, position = c("bottom", "right")) {

    plots <- list(...)
    position <- match.arg(position)
    g <- ggplotGrob(plots[[1]] + theme(legend.position = position))$grobs
    legend <- g[[which(sapply(g, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")]]
    lheight <- sum(legend$height)
    lwidth <- sum(legend$width)
    gl <- lapply(plots, function(x) x + theme(legend.position="none"))
    gl <- c(gl, ncol = ncol, nrow = nrow)

    combined <- switch(position,
                 "bottom" = arrangeGrob(do.call(arrangeGrob, gl),
                                        legend,
                                        ncol = 1,
                                        heights = unit.c(unit(1, "npc") -  lheight, lheight)),
                       "right" = arrangeGrob(do.call(arrangeGrob, gl),
                                       legend,
                                       ncol = 2,
                                       widths = unit.c(unit(1, "npc") - lwidth, lwidth)))

    grid.newpage()
    grid.draw(combined)

    # return gtable invisibly
    invisible(combined)

    }

    grid_arrange_shared_legend (p1,p2)
```

[image]

Using the `grid_arrange_shared_legend()` function here means that the unique legend is correct only for one of the plots on the grid

**Question** How to preserve (extract?) the unique legends and plot them above each plot on the grid but keep the common legend at the bottom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise using `cowplot` here. In this case it's easiest to combine two `plot_grid` calls, then get the legend with `get_legend`:

```
library(ggplot2)

#reduce the number of points to plot
diamonds2 <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 500), ]

p1<- ggplot(diamonds2, aes(x=price, y= depth, color= clarity , shape= cut )) +
  geom_point(size=5) + labs (shape = "unique legend", color = "common legend") +
  theme(legend.position = "top")

p2 <- ggplot(diamonds2, aes(x=price, y= depth, color= clarity , shape= color )) +
  geom_point(size=5) + labs (shape = "unique legend", color = "common legend") +
  theme(legend.position = "top")

cowplot::plot_grid(
  cowplot::plot_grid(
    p1 + scale_color_discrete(guide = FALSE),
    p2 + scale_color_discrete(guide = FALSE),
    align = 'h'
  ),
  cowplot::get_legend(p1 + scale_shape(guide = FALSE) + theme(legend.position = "bottom")),
  nrow = 2, rel_heights = c(4, 1)
)
```

[image]