# Combine multiple ggplots into one plot with shared gradient legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have multiple ggplots, currently they have different gradient legends. I want to use the grid extra package to create a plot containing all plots such as in
[Add a common Legend for combined ggplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649473/add-a-common-legend-for-combined-ggplots)

However, that solution applies to grouped discrete data. Is there a way to make this apply to my gradient legend.

Comment: [Here's a nice vignette](https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/shared_legends.html) about doing this using `extract_legend` from the `cowplot` package. If you need more "hands on" help, you will need to post a reproducible example for us to assist you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more information (for instance current code along with `dput` output), it's very difficult to answer your question.

However, based on your speech only, the `{patchwork}` package ([link](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/)) seems best suited for this kind of operation.

For instance, you could write this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(mpg, disp, color=hp))
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(drat, wt, color=hp))

p1 + p2
```

[image]

```
p1 + p2 + plot_layout(guides = 'collect')
```

[image]

Comment: Just as a sidenote, the two legends from the plots you are combining should have the exact same limits, breaks, labels, name etc. otherwise they won't be collected.