# ggplot Fix Legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
set.seed(1)
DATA = data.frame(STUDENT = c(1:100),
                  SCORE = sample(1:1000))
```

If I run this code below I generate many graph but the legend/scale changes every time, how do I make it stay the same?

```
DATA %>%
  sample_n(10) %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = STUDENT, y = SCORE, color = SCORE) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = rainbow(5))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649473/add-a-common-legend-for-combined-ggplots

Comment: @milo thank you it is not the same because I am not combined graphs

Comment: ggplot doesn't know the range of possible values, it only knows the values in your data. You can set the scale limits in your `scale_color_gradientn` call with e.g.  `limits = c(1, 1000)`

Comment: @GregorThomas thank you I try ' + ylim(0,1000)' but it didn't work..

Comment: Right, you want to set the limits of the color scale, not the y scale, so `ylim` won't work. Change `scale_color_gradientn(colours = rainbow(5))` to `scale_color_gradientn(colours = rainbow(5), limits = c(1, 1000))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the same legend you can fix the `limits=` of the scale, e.g. using `limits = c(1, 1000)`:

```r
set.seed(1)
DATA <- data.frame(
  STUDENT = c(1:100),
  SCORE = sample(1:1000)
)

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

make_plot <- function() {
  DATA %>%
    sample_n(10) %>%
    ggplot() +
    aes(x = STUDENT, y = SCORE, color = SCORE) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_color_gradientn(
      colours = rainbow(5),
      limits = c(1, 1000)
    )
}

make_plot()
```

[image]

```r
make_plot()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you this is really perfect and I have a finally question...since the scale fixed now you can't always see the colors good. is it possible to code like :

if value < 200, gradients of blue; if value = 200 black, if value >200 gradients red? and fix this on scale?

Comment: You could try with the `values=` argument, i.e. do `scale_color_gradientn(
      colors = c("blue", "white", "red"),
      values = c(0, 200, 1000) / 1000,
      limits = c(1, 1000)
    )`. I used `white` but you could try with `black` as the mid color.