# ggplot2 grid_arrange_shared_legend produces empty plot/page

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, grid-layout

The following script

```
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)

grid_arrange_shared_legend <- function(plots) {
  g <- ggplotGrob(plots[[1]] + theme(legend.position="bottom"))$grobs
  legend <- g[[which(sapply(g, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")]]
  lheight <- sum(legend$height)
  grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(grobs=lapply(plots, function(x)
    x + theme(legend.position="none")),ncol = 3),
    legend,
    ncol = 1,
    heights = unit.c(unit(1, "npc") - lheight, lheight))
}
plotList <- list()
df <- data.frame(value=rnorm(10))

for (i in 1:12){
  plotList[[i]] <- qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data = iris, color = Species)
}
pdf("plots.pdf",width=12.21/2.54, height=20.92/2.54)
grid_arrange_shared_legend(plotList)
dev.off()
```

Results in a two page pdf. The first page is empty. The second page contains the desired grid of plots.

Why is the first page empty and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the first page is empty. But setting `onefile = FALSE` in `pdf` solves the issue.

```
pdf("plots.pdf",width=12.21/2.54, height=20.92/2.54,onefile=FALSE)
```

There is another question in Stack Overflow related to this issue.
[In R, how to prevent blank page in pdf when using gridBase to embed subplot inside plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481267/in-r-how-to-prevent-blank-page-in-pdf-when-using-gridbase-to-embed-subplot-insi)