# Plotting bar charts on map using ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, maps, bar-chart

I would like to produce a barplot for each location on a map using ggplot2,
as was done by xingmowang with base graphics and a number of packages:

http://nzprimarysectortrade.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/let-r-fly-visualizing-export-data-using-r/

[image]

This is related to [Embedding a miniature plot within a plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793935/embedding-a-miniature-plot-within-a-plot).

For the moment, the best I can do is match value to point size in a jittered point plot:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(maps)

#Get world map info
world_map <- map_data("world")

#Creat a base plot
p <- ggplot() + coord_fixed()

#Add map to base plot
base_world <- p + geom_polygon(data=world_map,
                               aes(x=long,
                                   y=lat,
                                   group=group))


#Create example data
geo_data <- data.frame(long=c(20,20,100,100,20,20,100,100),
                       lat=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                       value=c(10,30,40,50,20,20,100,100),
                       Facet=rep(c("Facet_1", "Facet_2"), 4),
                       colour=rep(c("colour_1", "colour_2"), each=4))

#Creat an example plot
map_with_jitter <- base_world+geom_point(data=geo_data,
                                            aes(x=long,
                                                y=lat,
                                                colour=colour,
                                                size=value),
                                         position="jitter",
                                         alpha=I(0.5))

#Add faceting
map_with_jitter <- map_with_jitter + facet_wrap(~Facet)

map_with_jitter <- map_with_jitter + theme(legend.position="none")

print(map_with_jitter)
```

[image: Example map plot with ggplot2]

With an inelegant workaround:

```
subset_data <- geo_data[geo_data$Facet=="Facet_1" &
                          geo_data$long=="20",]
subplot <- qplot(data=subset_data,
                 x=colour,
                 y=value,
                 fill=colour,
                 geom="bar",
                 stat="identity")+theme(legend.position="none")

print(base_world)
print(subplot, vp=viewport((200+mean(subset_data$long))/400,(100+mean(subset_data$lat))/200 , .2, .2))
```

[image]

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368180/plotting-pie-graphs-on-map-in-ggplot

Comment: What is the question here? What have you tried?

Comment: see `?annotation_custom` for an example of inset graphic

Comment: [ggsubplots](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggsubplot/index.html)?

Comment: You can indeed use ggsubplots to achieve this.See my answer below

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Update 2016-12-23**: The `ggsubplot`-package is no longer actively maintained and is [archived on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggsubplot/index.html):

> Package ‘ggsubplot’ was removed from the CRAN repository.>
>   Formerly available versions can be obtained from the archive.>
>   Archived on 2016-01-11 as requested by the maintainer garrett@rstudio.com.

`ggsubplot` will not work with R versions >= 3.1.0. Install R 3.0.3 to run the code below:

---

You can indeed achieve this by means of the `ggsubplot` package like Baptiste suggests.

```
library(ggsubplot)
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
library(plyr)

#Get world map info
world_map <- map_data("world")

#Create a base plot
p <- ggplot()  + geom_polygon(data=world_map,aes(x=long, y=lat,group=group))

# Calculate the mean longitude and latitude per region, these will be the coördinates where the plots will be placed, so you can tweak them where needed.
# Create simulation data of the age distribution per region and merge the two.

centres <- ddply(world_map,.(region),summarize,long=mean(long),lat=mean(lat))
mycat <- cut(runif(1000), c(0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 1), labels=FALSE) 
mycat <- as.factor(mycat)
age <- factor(mycat,labels=c("<15","15-30","20-60",">60"))
simdat <- merge(centres ,age)
colnames(simdat) <- c( "region","long","lat","Age" )

# Select the countries where you want a subplot for and plot
simdat2 <- subset(simdat, region %in% c("USA","China","USSR","Brazil", "Australia"))
(testplot <- p+geom_subplot2d(aes(long, lat, subplot = geom_bar(aes(Age, ..count.., fill = Age))), bins = c(15,12), ref = NULL, width = rel(0.8), data = simdat2))
```

Result:[image]

Comment: Any way to add a y axis or at least a reference bar showing the hight of a given number of units on the y axis (ref : ref_box, ref_hline, ref_vline only allow you to specify relative to plot area not y axis units)?  I guess one could add a known data point to each bin with a known value on the y axis which would then be presented in the legend.  Any other solutions?

Comment: Could someone possibly clarify how `geom_bar`'s `..count..` argument works?

Comment: Alternatively: `simdat3 = plyr::count(simdat2, vars = c('region','long','lat','Age'))` and plot with `p + geom_subplot(data=simdat3, aes(long, lat, group=region, subplot = geom_bar(aes(Age, freq, fill = Age), stat="identity")),width = 10, height=20)`

Comment: The other day, I could not replicate one of the examples with ggsubplot. Today, I tried this example, but I could not replicate it. I had an error message saying `Error in layout_base(data, vars, drop = drop) : At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting`. I wonder if you have the same error message. Could you test your script?

Comment: @jazurro Still working for me. Which version of `ggplot2` are you using?

Comment: I got the same error message as jazzurro.  I'm running ggplot2 version 3.1.3.

Comment: I also get this error using ggplot2 version 1.01 (R version 3.1.2).

Comment: This seems to be a known issue related to the R version ( >= R 3.1.0). https://github.com/garrettgman/ggsubplot/issues/10