# Specifying plot order with ggsubplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm adding bar-plots to maps using ggplot and ggsubplot, but cannot figure out how to specify which to plot first.  I'd like to plot the northerly ones first so they sit behind any overlapping plots.  With a low fill alpha these should still be viewable.  This is the workflow:

```
library(ggsubplot)
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
library(plyr)

world_map = map_data("world")
(p = ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = world_map, aes(x=long, y=lat,group=group)))

d = ddply(world_map,.(region),summarize,long=mean(long),lat=mean(lat))
d = d[sample(1:nrow(d), 50),]
d = rbind(d,d)
d$cat = rep(c('A','B'), each=nrow(d)/2)
d$value = sample(1:10, nrow(d), rep=T)
head(d)

p + geom_subplot(data=d, aes(long, lat, group=region, subplot = geom_bar(aes(cat, value, fill=cat), 
                 col='black', alpha=0.9, stat="identity")), width = 30, height=30)
```

[image]

As you can see the plot order seems pretty random.  So I tried to change region (country) to an ordered factor:

```
d$region = factor(d$region, ordered=T)
(ord = count(d[,c('region','lat')], vars=c('region','lat')))
ordered_levels = order(ord$lat, decreasing=T)
print(ord[ordered_levels,])
levels(d$region) = levels(d$region)[ordered_levels]
levels(d$region)

p + geom_subplot(data=d, aes(long, lat, group=region, subplot = geom_bar(aes(cat, value, fill=cat), 
                 col='black', alpha=0.9, stat="identity")), width = 30, height=30)
```

But this does not seem to solve the problem.  Very grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind?

[image]

You need to order `d` by latitude, as you pointed out, and also use `group=lat` in the call to `geom_subplot(...)`.

```
set.seed(1)
d = ddply(world_map,.(region),summarize,long=mean(long),lat=mean(lat))
d = d[sample(1:nrow(d), 50),]
d = rbind(d,d)
d$cat = rep(c('A','B'), each=nrow(d)/2)
d$value = sample(1:10, nrow(d), rep=T)
d <- d[order(d$lat),]
head(d)
p + geom_subplot(data=d, aes(long, lat, group=lat, 
      subplot = geom_bar(aes(cat, value, fill=cat), 
        col='black', alpha=0.9, stat="identity")), width = 30, height=30)
```

Comment: Thanks jlhoward. That does somehow seem to sort the plot order. I'm not sure `d <- d[order(d$lat),]` has any effect - without it the resulting plot is the same. But I think the `group=lat` is on the right track :)

Comment: Try `aes(...,group=-lat)`.

Comment: `group=-lat`. genius. :)

Answer (score 1):

The underlying map was pretty much of a mess in the resulting figure, but this pre-ordering seemed to bring the high latitude items to the front:

```
world_map = world_map[order(world_map$lat),]
```

It wasn't clear whether you wanted the negative latitudes to be plotted under the latitudes nearer the Equator, so you also have the option of using abs(world_map$lat) as the order.

Comment: Thanks for reply, although I don't get how this is supposed to work. If its about changing the data order, why not `d = d[order(d$lat),]` instead?  But either way the plots don't happen in any latitudinal order for me.  Some northerly plots still plot on top of southerly ones.

Comment: I intended the northerly points to always overplot the southerly points. I _thought_ that was what you asked for, or rather I inferred it and asked that you clarify what was intended. I suppose ordering after the ddply operation would be safer. I obviously wasn't clear about the (unstated) overall strategy.

Comment: Sorry for any ambiguity - like I said I need to plot the northerly ones first :)

Comment: Ah. The wouldn't it instead be `d <- d[rev(order(d$lat)), ]` or `world_map = world_map[rev(order(world_map$lat)),]`?

Comment: It seems the group argument is the determinant. I didn't see that coming!