# r mapplots - draw.barplot2D for adding graphs to maps

Tags: r, graph, dictionary

I have been using add.pie to add pie charts to maps and it works well. I would like to use draw.barplot2D to add bar charts to maps. I can’t get it to work at all. I'm not sure if it’s because my data is in the wrong shape or if I'm specifying things badly. I have tried stepping through it by adding simple numbers to the code instead of referencing arrays, but that has not worked either. Has anyone used this successfully?

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), which will include (among other things) the package(s) that those functions are from.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20465070/barplots-on-a-map/20468836#20468836) might help.