# tiny pie charts to represent each point in an scatterplot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart, scatter-plot

I want to create a scatter plot, in which each point is a tiny pie chart. For instance consider following data:

```
foo <- data.frame(X=runif(30), Y=runif(30),A=runif(30),B=runif(30),C=runif(30))
```

The following code will make a scatter plot, representing `X` and `Y` values of each point:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
foo.m <- melt(foo, id.vars=c("X","Y"))
ggplot(foo.m, aes(X,Y))+geom_point()
```

[image]

And the following code will make a pie chart for each point:

```
p <- ggplot(foo.m, aes(variable,value,fill=variable)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
p + coord_polar() + facet_wrap(~X+Y,,ncol=6) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

But I am looking to merge them: creating a scatter plot in which each point is replaced by the pie chart. This way I will be able to show all 5 values (X, Y, A, B, C) of each record in the same chart.

Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: @hrbrmstr Why? I have abstracted some points, X and Y come from Principal Components Analysis (PCA). A, B and C are the properties of each record (Actually they are 6, not 3). Do you have a better idea for showing them in a PCA plot?

Comment: bar charts > pie charts. always.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Pie charts can be put as small circles on a scatter plot, each representing a point. But how we can put bar plots on a scatter plot?

Comment: How about facetting by `variable` (whatever you have `fill` set to in your pies) and letting the size of the point (in each facet) be whatever you have as the radius of each pie.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the sort of thing you can do with package **ggsubplot**.  Unfortunately, according to issue #10 [here](https://github.com/garrettgman/ggsubplot/issues/10), this package is not working with R 3.1.1.  I ran it successfully if I used an older version of R (3.0.3).

Using your long dataset, you could put bar plots at each `X`, `Y` point like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsubplot)

ggplot(foo.m) +
    geom_subplot2d(aes(x = X, y = Y, 
                    subplot = geom_bar(aes(variable, value, fill = variable), stat = "identity")),
                width = rel(.5), ref = NULL)
```

[image]

This gives the basic idea, although there are many other options (like controlling where the subplots move to when there is overlap in plot space).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20468836/2461552) has more information on the status of **ggsubplot** with newer R versions.

Comment: Thank you. I have R 3.1.1 and as you told it results in an error. Could you please add a snapshot of your plot in the answer?

Answer (score 2):

there is a package, scatterpie, that does exactly what you want to do!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scatterpie)

ggplot() + 
  geom_scatterpie(aes(x=X, y=Y, r=0.1), data=foo.m, cols=c("A", "B", "C"))
```

In the aesthetics, r is the radius of the pie, you can adjust as necessary.  It is dependent on the scale of the graph - since your graph goes from 0.0 to 1.0, a radius of 1 would take up the entire graph (if centered at 0.5, 0.5).

Do note that while you will get a legend for the pie slice colors, it will not (to my knowledge) label the slices themselves on the pies.