# How to add the legend for the barchart superimposed onto a ggplot2 map (annotation_custom)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In: [*"How to plot barchart onto ggplot2 map"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063043/how-to-plot-barchart-onto-ggplot2-map)
Inscaven has proposed an efficient way for adding barplot onto a map without using subplot library.

But how adding the legend for any barplot since 
theme(legend.position = "topright") does not work ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to place the legend in the top right corner, instead of `"topright"` you can specify a legend position as coordinates:

```
ggplot(...) + theme(legend.position = c(0.9, 0.9))
```

`(0,0)` corresponds to the bottom left corner and `(1,1)` is top right.