# Arranging pROC output in a grid with a grob

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I'd like to somehow arrange the wonderful ROC curves produced by the pROC package together with the wonderful tables arranged as grobs.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to arrange it using grid.extra, push it into a viewport, or effectively use par.  The last method doesn't place nice with grid.extra, and the the former methods don't work with plot.roc.  Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this truly does do what I want:
[Embedding a miniature plot within a plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793935/embedding-a-miniature-plot-within-a-plot)