# ggplot: overlay two plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to overlay two plots with gridExtra (or other package)?

I want to rescale one plot and overlay it to a second one (specifying rescaling and coordinates)

```
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)

df <- data.frame(value=rnorm(10), date=1:10)

p1 <- ggplot(data.frame(df), aes(value,date)) + geom_line()
p2 <- ggplot(data.frame(df), aes(value,date)) + geom_point()
```

to obtain something like this

[image]

Comment: `p1 ; print(p2,vp=viewport(.8, .75, .4, 0.4) )`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embedding a miniature plot within a plot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793935/embedding-a-miniature-plot-within-a-plot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at `gtable` package in combination with `gridExtra`. You can specify size and coordinates of plot as you like.

```
require(gtable)

p1 <- ggplotGrob(p1)
p2 <- ggplotGrob(p2)

gt <- gtable(widths = unit(c(1, 2), "null"), heights = unit(c(.2, 1, 1), "null"))
gt <- gtable_add_grob(gt, p2, t = 1, b = 3, l = 1, r = 2)
gt <- gtable_add_grob(gt, p1, t = 2, l = 2)
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

Comment: You'll need to load `grid` package to be able to use `grid.draw`

Comment: Could you be so kind to explain how we can specify coordinates for the plots? Because I can't find how it works. Thank you.