# ggplot2: add distribution jitter near the legend bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

### A non-trivial `ggplot` challenge

I compare the spatial distribution of a variable at two moments using maps with a fixed color scale - to show the actual change. It would be very nice to add the distributions of the variables near the legend bars as jitter points.

The desired plot should look something like the picture: the supposed **red** jitter points are added manually (I just used paint.net) to the plot produced by `R`.

[image]

---

### Reproduce the maps

To reproduce the maps, an `R` object called `fortIT` is required. This is a fortified (using `ggplot2::fortify`) SpatialPolygonsDataFrame of Italian NUTS-2 regions with the data attached. The **RData file** can be downloaded [**here**](https://ikashnitsky.github.io/share/1602-so-q-map-jitter/fortIT.RData) [89KB]

And the code for the maps:

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)
require(ggthemes)
require(gridExtra)
require(rgeos)
require(maptools)
require(cowplot)
require(viridis)

# load the data
load(url("https://ikashnitsky.github.io/share/1602-so-q-map-jitter/fortIT.RData"))

# produce the first map
gIT1 <- ggplot()+
        geom_polygon(data = fortIT, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=tsr03),
                     color='grey30',size=.1)+
        scale_fill_viridis('TSR\n2003',limits=range(fortIT[,9:10]))+ # !!! limits fix the color scale
        
        coord_equal(xlim=c(4000000, 5500000), ylim=c(1500000,3000000))+
        guides(fill = guide_colorbar(barwidth = 1.5, barheight = 15))+
        
        theme_map()+
        theme(panel.border=element_rect(color = 'black',size=.5,fill = NA),
              legend.position = c(1, 1),
              legend.justification = c(1, 1),
              legend.background = element_rect(colour = NA, fill = NA),
              legend.title = element_text(size=15),
              legend.text = element_text(size=15))+
        scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
        scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
        labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)


# produce the second map
gIT2 <- ggplot()+
        geom_polygon(data = fortIT, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=tsr43),
                     color='grey30',size=.1)+
        scale_fill_viridis('TSR\n2043',limits=range(fortIT[,9:10]))+
        
        coord_equal(xlim=c(4000000, 5500000), ylim=c(1500000,3000000))+
        guides(fill = guide_colorbar(barwidth = 1.5, barheight = 15))+
        
        theme_map()+
        theme(panel.border=element_rect(color = 'black',size=.5,fill = NA),
              legend.position = c(1, 1),
              legend.justification = c(1, 1),
              legend.background = element_rect(colour = NA, fill = NA),
              legend.title = element_text(size=15),
              legend.text = element_text(size=15))+
        scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
        scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
        labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)

# align both maps side by side
gIT <- plot_grid(gIT1,gIT2,ncol=2,labels=LETTERS[1:2],label_size=20)

ggsave('italy.png',gIT,width=12,height=7,dpi=192)
```

---

### Additional information

The variables visualized in the maps are Total Support Ratios in 2003 (panel A) and 2043 (panel B, Eurostat regional projection). Total Support Ratio is the ratio of *working-age population* (15-64) to *non-working-age population* (younger than 15 and older than 65).

Comment: Depending on the number of points you have, a histogram could also be used. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793935/embedding-a-miniature-plot-within-a-plot for examples.

Comment: I'll take a stab at it, but R is not truly a data viz tool. There are lots of visualization packages, but at the end of the day it saves time and produces better results to export something from R and use a dedicated viz tool like Tableau or GIMP.

Comment: @Hack-R That's the usual comment on a challenge like this. The thing is, it's much better to have a generic script solution rather than edit every plot manually.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik True. But that's not the crucial point. The main challenge, as I see it: I don't know how to ensure that the jitter point are located at the appropriate `y` coordinates.

Comment: @llya If that's the usual response, then it's probably correct. Both GIMP and Tableau fully support automation and scripting. Tableau is specifically designed for R session connectivity; GIMP supports scripts and plugins.

Comment: This will make loading and installing packages and their dependencies a little more concise and than repeated `require` or `library` statements: `pacman::p_load(dplyr, ggplot2, ggthemes, gridExtra, rgeos, maptools, cowplot, viridis)`. You only need to install pacman once and then you'll never have to type `install.packages` or `require` again.

Comment: @Hack-R Then, I must admit, I knew nothing about the true capabilities of GIMP or Tableau. Still, I'd like to learn a (preferably simple) `ggplot2` solution. Thanks for the `pacman` tip! I will definitely use the package.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the figure from the question but don't seem to be able to download the `fortIT` data file. Google drive tells me I don't have permission. Is it possible to save the file elsewhere (e.g. in a gist) or provide the code that fortifies the map?

Comment: Sorry, I recently rearranged my gdrive. [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1Cid1hm5YLRZVJSQVZwQUdYLTA) is the updated link

Comment: Btw., I think your example code loads a number of libraries that aren’t required. It should run with only `ggplot2`, `cowplot`, and `viridis`. (`cowplot` has a `theme_map()` now, it’s just `theme_void()` with a different default font size. `theme_void()` works great for maps.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever a custom legend is required, I find it preferable to draw the legend as a separate plot and then combine.

For example, we can define the following function:

```
plot_legend <- function(dots, limits, title, bins = 20) {
  n <- 100
  tiles <- data.frame(x = rep(0.5, n),
                      y = seq(limits[1], limits[2], length.out = n))

  ggplot() +
    geom_raster(data=tiles, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = y), interpolate = TRUE) +
    geom_dotplot(data = data.frame(x = dots), aes(x = -.05, y = x, fill = ..y..),
                 stackdir = "down", binaxis = "y", binwidth = diff(limits)/bins, dotsize = .8) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-5, 1), expand = c(0, 0)) +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), position = "right") +
    ggtitle(title) +
    theme_cowplot(12) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
          axis.line = element_blank(),
          axis.title = element_blank(),
          plot.title = element_text(face = "plain", hjust = 1),
          legend.position = "none")
}
```

Which we can use like so:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(cowplot)
require(viridis)

dots <- 3*runif(100)
range <- c(0, 3)
plot_legend(dots, range, "random numbers") + scale_fill_viridis()
```

[image]

Now we use this together with the maps code. It requires a little bit of fiddling with the final placement of the legends into the figures, but it's not overly complicated.

```
require(dplyr)
load(url("https://ikashnitsky.github.io/misc/160227-SO-question/fortIT.RData"))

# extract tsr03 and tsr43 data
fortIT %>% group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(tsr03 = tsr03[1], tsr43 = tsr43[1]) -> df_tsr

# get color range limits
limits <- range(fortIT[,9:10])

# make the legends
legIT1 <- plot_legend(df_tsr$tsr03, limits, "TSR 2003") + scale_fill_viridis()
legIT2 <- plot_legend(df_tsr$tsr43, limits, "TSR 2043") + scale_fill_viridis()

# produce the first map
gIT1 <- ggplot()+
  geom_polygon(data = fortIT, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=tsr03),
               color='grey30', size=.1) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_fill_viridis('TSR\n2003', limits = limits, guide = "none") +
  coord_equal(xlim=c(4000000, 5500000), ylim=c(1500000, 3000000)) +
  theme_map() +
  theme(panel.border=element_rect(color = 'black',size=.5,fill = NA))

# produce the second map
gIT2 <- ggplot()+
  geom_polygon(data = fortIT, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=tsr43),
               color='grey30',size=.1)+
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_fill_viridis('TSR\n2043', limits = limits, guide = "none") +
  coord_equal(xlim=c(4000000, 5500000), ylim=c(1500000, 3000000)) +
  theme_map() +
  theme(panel.border=element_rect(color = 'black',size=.5,fill = NA))

# put everything together
plot_grid(ggdraw(gIT1) + draw_plot(legIT1, .62, .35, .35, .55),
          ggdraw(gIT2) + draw_plot(legIT2, .62, .35, .35, .55),
          ncol=2, labels="AUTO")
```

[image]

Two comments:

1. The size of the stacked points can be controlled by the `bins` argument of the `plot_legend()` function. The larger `bins`, the smaller the points.
2. I would typically remove the frames around each map, but I tried here to reproduce the original figure as closely as possible.

Comment: This is a neat solution. I just wonder if it is possible to write an extension for basic `ggplot` that would add such distributions with just one parameter input from the user, e.g. `theme(legend.hist = TRUE)` or `theme(legend.density = TRUE)`. Is there a clear path towards such an add-on?

Comment: While ggplot2 has a mechanism for writing new legend types, I don’t know that it’s possible to get any of the data into the legend-drawing code.

Answer (score 6):

you could replace the legend with one that has a plot panel stuck to it with the density information,

```
g <- ggplotGrob(p)
leg = gtable_filter(g, "guide-box")

dd <- ddply(fortIT, "group", summarise, fill=unique(tsr03))
dum <- ggplot(dd, aes(0,y=fill)) +
  geom_dotplot(fill="red", binaxis = "y", dotsize=0.5, stackdir = "down")+
  scale_y_continuous(lim=range(fortIT[,c("tsr03", "tsr43")]), expand=c(0,0)) +
  theme_void() 

dummy_panel <- gtable_filter(ggplotGrob(dum), "panel")
dummy_panel$layout$clip <- FALSE

a <- leg[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]
a <- gtable_add_cols(a, unit(1,"cm"), 0)
a <- gtable_add_grob(a, dummy_panel, 4, 1)
a$layout$clip <- FALSE
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(a)

leg[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]] <- a
g$grobs[g$layout$name=="guide-box"] <- list(leg)

library(grid)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Something, probably, went wrong at the step `dd <- ddply(fortIT, "group", summarise, fill=unique(tsr03))`, as there are 21 regions, but the `dotplot` produces 27 dots. I will fix it. Thanks a lot for the solution!

Comment: I'm guessing the 28 group values are physical closed polygons, some of them being tiny islands that are part of a bigger region.

Comment: I bet, you are right. It should be `dd <- ddply(fortIT, "group", summarise, fill=unique(id))` in the code