# How to combine two equivalence plots (lattice) in R?

Tags: r, graphics, lattice, equivalence

I would like to add two equivalence plots together for the following lattice graphics.  My usual trick for the `plot()` function `par(mfcol=c(1,2))` does not work with these lattice-based graphs.  I have looked at the related posts, although I cannot seem to extract the information I need from the solutions.  How can I combine the following equivalence plots so that they are adjacent (side by side) to each other in the output?  Or, in other words, what is the lattice equivalent to `par(mfcol=c(1,2))`?

```
require(equivalence)

# Simplified data for equivalence plot 1
a = c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18)
b = c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17)
mydata1 = data.frame(a,b)

equivalence.xyplot(mydata1$b ~ mydata1$a,
                   alpha=0.05, b0.ii=0.25, b1.ii=0.25)


# Simplified data for equivalence plot 2
x = c(1,4,8,2,3,4,6,5,9)
y = c(2,4,7,3,3,4,7,5,9)
mydata2 = data.frame(x,y)

equivalence.xyplot(mydata2$y ~ mydata2$x,
                   alpha=0.05, b0.ii=0.25, b1.ii=0.25)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540129/lattice-multiple-plots-in-one-window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540129/lattice-multiple-plots-in-one-window) in the comments by @mplourde, the following alterations to the code arrange the graphs to my specs:

```
require(equivalence)

# Simplified data for equivalence plot 1
a = c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18)
b = c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17)
mydata1 = data.frame(a,b)

px1 = equivalence.xyplot(mydata1$b ~ mydata1$a,
                   alpha=0.05, b0.ii=0.25, b1.ii=0.25)

# Simplified data for equivalence plot 2
x = c(1,4,8,2,3,4,6,5,9)
y = c(2,4,7,3,3,4,7,5,9)
mydata2 = data.frame(x,y)

px2 = equivalence.xyplot(mydata2$y ~ mydata2$x,
                   alpha=0.05, b0.ii=0.25, b1.ii=0.25)

print(px1, position=c(0, 0.5, .5, 1), more=TRUE)
print(px2, position=c(0.5, 0.5, 1, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I think the `gridExtra` answer in the linked post also deserves ample attention.