# Multiple graphs within plot with loop

Tags: r

How to get graph for each column of data.frame within one plot with loop? Must be easy just can't figure it out.

Sample data:

```
rdata <- data.frame(y=rnorm(1000,2,2),v1=rnorm(1000,1,1),v2=rnorm(1000,3,3),
                    v3=rnorm(1000,4,4),v4=rnorm(1000,5,5))
```

What I have tried?

```
library(lattice)

p <- par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for(i in 2:5){
w <- xyplot(y~rdata[,i],rdata)
print(w)
}
par(p)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have to use `lattice` you can just use base `plot` instead and it should work as you want.

```
p <- par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for(i in 2:5){
    plot(y~rdata[,i],rdata)
}
par(p)
```

[image]

If you want to use `lattice` look this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2540573/2195555). Lattice ignores `par`, so you have to do some more work to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks, yes I know it works with `plot` but I have done so far everything in lattice so can't change now to different layout/setup. I will look into your reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Inorder to easily arrange a bunch of lattice plots, I like to use the helper function [print.plotlist](https://gist.github.com/MrFlick/11146470). It has a `layout=` parameter that acts like the `layout()` function for base graphics. For example, you could call

```
rdata <- data.frame(y=rnorm(1000,2,2),v1=rnorm(1000,1,1),v2=rnorm(1000,3,3),
                    v3=rnorm(1000,4,4),v4=rnorm(1000,5,5))

library(lattice)
plots<-lapply(2:5, function(i) {xyplot(y~rdata[,i],rdata)})
print.plotlist(plots, layout=matrix(1:4, ncol=2))
```

to get

[image]

Otherwise you normally use a `split=` parameter to the print statement to place a plot in a subsection of the device. For example, you could also do

```
print(plots[[1]], split=c(1,1,2,2), more=T)
print(plots[[2]], split=c(1,2,2,2), more=T)
print(plots[[3]], split=c(2,1,2,2), more=T)
print(plots[[4]], split=c(2,2,2,2))
```

Comment: I have figured it out in meantime but this is different approach I can learn from. Thanks!