# How do I plot two models into one graph

Tags: r, plot

I used DoseFinds to building the two models and I want to 
plot both model on the same graph to compare.

```
library(DoseFinding)
doses <- c(0, 10, 25, 50, 100, 150)
fmodels <- Mods(emax = 25,
            doses=doses, placEff = 0.5, maxEff = -0.4,
            addArgs=list(scal=200))

fmodels2 <- Mods(emax = 25,
            doses=doses, placEff = -1.5, maxEff = -1.4,
            addArgs=list(scal=200))
plot(fmodels)
plot(fmodels2)
```

Comment: this is not duplicate! i want to plot on the same graph not separate them

Comment: what class is fmodels?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plot 2 graphs in same plot in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564258/plot-2-graphs-in-same-plot-in-r)

Comment: @ipkallwin You are not helping your cause with your outbreaks and personal attacks. Instead you should try to do this yourself and demonstrate some effort.

Comment: @SeñorO Class "Mods" and the plot method uses lattice.

Comment: I think this is a better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2540129/324364

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436551/how-to-plot-two-models-in-the-same-graph

Comment: Please read the solutions at the link I provided. It is a different question with different solutions. In particular, look at the `gridExtra` answer.

Comment: @joran The asker doesn't want two plots in one window. They want to combine the plot data in one plot.

Comment: @Roland Are you sure? That wasn't clear to me from the question.

Comment: @joran After looking at the plot from the example in the docs I believe so. It's a facetted lattice plot where each panel shows one type of model.

Comment: Where `doses <- c(0, 10, 25, 50, 100, 150)` as in the first example in the docs for `Mods`?

Comment: sorry they kept deleting my post, yes there is doses<-c(0......

Answer (score 4):

Combine the two things into one object:

```
doses <- c(0, 10, 25, 50, 100, 150)
fmodels2 <- Mods(emax = c(25,25),
doses=doses, placEff = c(0.5,-1.5), maxEff = c(-0.4,-1.4),
addArgs=list(scal=200))
```

then plot with `superpose=TRUE`:

```
plot(fmodels2, superpose=TRUE)
```

[image]

The two lines don't overlap much so although it looks like two separate graphs, it isnt!

Comment: thanks~~this is what I really want...thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to use superpose = TRUE when you call the plot-function (?plot.Mods). This will plot the models in the same graph if they are in the same Mods-object. See ?Mods for how to have more than one model in the same object.