# How to add values to a R plot with 4 subplots

Tags: r, plot

I have looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449523/how-do-i-plot-two-models-into-one-graph?lq=1) but it is not quite what I want. Using superpose seems not to be working.

the plot function in R is really powerful. Applied to different objects, will give different results. When applied to the results of the fevd function (from extRemes package), it constructs a 2x2 set of plots (that can be slightly different depending on the model). [here](http://pybonacci.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/wpid-Trabajando_con_Python_y_R2.png) you can find an example.

After re-writing my own GEV fitting routines, I want to test my results against fevd's results. I want to plot my results on top of fevd's plots.

How do I extract the handles (does R has handles? objects?) of the plots and tell R, for example:

mimicking python

```
ax = plt.subplot(221)
ax.plot(myxdata, myydata, 'o')
```

mimicking matlab

```
subplot(2,2,1)
hold on
plot(myxdata, myydata, 'o')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `par()$mfg` to check/set which plot on the current figure to use.  For example,

```
## Make a 2x2 figure
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
for(i in 1:4) plot(1,1, ylim=c(0,10), xlim=c(0,10))

## Current plot in focus
par()$mfg
# [1] 2 2 2 2

## Go back and put some points on the second figure
par(mfg=c(1,2))  # c(row, col)
points(1:10, col=1:10)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! it did access the figure! but I think the fevd plots are manipulated in a way that I cannot plot over. Although the two plots look identical separately (same x/y range and visually identical) when I plot my new data, they are all squeezed in a corner. like if the two range of values were different, but they are not. I will try to post a figure. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can plot on same object.
but to make this kind of plot, just use this syntax:

```
par(mfcol=c(2,2)) # divide the plotting space into 4 plots
plot(...) # first plot
plot(...) # second plot
plot(...) # third plot
plot(...) # fourth plot
```

Comment: thanks - I knew that. But  I really want to learn how to interact with plots obtained from plot(object...) where object could be the results of a variety of R packages.