# xyplot panels in the wrong order

Tags: r, lattice

I have a problem plotting my xyplot.
My table is ordered by day but I can't get the right order from Tuesday to Sunday.
I have tried to add `as.table=T` but it's not working. Any tips ?

```
    data <- read.csv("exemple.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";")
    attach(data)
    xyplot(Nos~Period|Day,layout=c(6,1),type="o")
    detach(data)
```

Moreover, I would like to add a second "line" of panels for the column `Cas`. I know if I want to add on the same panel I just have to write :

```
xyplot(Nos+Cas~Period|Day,layout=c(6,1),type="o")
```

Here is my data:

```
     Day    Period  Cas Nos Bis
1   Tuesday     1   131 14  176
2   Tuesday     2   203 107 138
3   Tuesday     3   118 163 131
4   Wednesday   1   143 80  165
5   Wednesday   2   232 151 158
6   Wednesday   3   130 101 143
7   Thursday    1   203 151 275
8   Thursday    2   165 108 134
9   Thursday    3   120 90  109
10  Friday      1   99  60  128
11  Friday      2   367 232 155
12  Friday      3   216 248 154
13  Saturday    1   158 134 184
14  Saturday    2   295 187 175
15  Saturday    3   210 310 145
16  Sunday      1   115 73  114
17  Sunday      2   232 124 160
18  Sunday      3   211 133 144
```

Thank you !

Lisa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this code without creating factors and reordering levels

```
xyplot(Nos~Period|I(Day),layout=c(6,1),type="o", index.cond=list(c(5,4,6, 1:3)))
```

**index.cond** reorder the plot as you wish

Comment: do you know how I have to do to add a second "line" of panels for the column Cas ? (I don't want to have on the same panel as I would get if i would write `Nos+Cas~Period | Day`)

Comment: Hi I have found something  here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540129/lattice-multiple-plots-in-one-window). 
You can use the package **gridExtra** and then the function **grid.arrange** like this :
`p1 = xyplot(Cas~Period|Day ...)
p2 = xyplot(Nos~Period|Day, ...)
require(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1,p2, nrow=2)`
Hope this what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that 'Day'  is a factor, and that the levels are in the order you wish the panels to appear; by default they will be alphabetical.

```
lvls = paste0(c("Mon", "Tues", "Wednes", "Thurs", "Fri", "Satur", "Sun"),
              "day")
data$Day = factor(data$Day, levels=lvls)
```