# How to plot multiple Dotplots in R with Hmisc package

Tags: r, graph, hmisc

So I've been trying to get two Dotplots (Hmisc package) to turn up in the same graph but R draws them sequentially instead.

Anybody know how to draw two Dotplots in the same graph, specifically using the Hmisc package?

I've tried somethings like

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
Dotplot(latitude~mortality, data=USmelanoma)
Dotplot(longitude~mortality, data=USmelanoma)
```

But it draws them in two seperate graphs, one after the other instead of in one graph, as I had expect par(mfrow = c(1,2)) to do

Comment: `par()` works only for base graphics. `Dotplot` uses the Lattice library. Try searching for combing lattice or ggplot2 plots (they both use `grid` graphics). I'm sure you'll find other answers out there.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540129/lattice-multiple-plots-in-one-window

Comment: @WhiteViking Good spot - thanks.

Comment: Thanks for finding the dup @WhiteViking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't mix base graphics with lattice graphics which you are trying to do here (well, you can but not easily and not in the manner you are trying to do here).

One way is to use the `grid.arrange()` function in the **gridExtra** package, e.g.

```
## load packages required
library("HSAUR2")
library("Hmisc")
library("gridExtra")

## draw each plot separately and save to objects
plt1 <- Dotplot(latitude ~ mortality, data = USmelanoma)
plt2 <- Dotplot(longitude ~ mortality, data = USmelanoma)

## arrange the stored plots
grid.arrange(plt1, plt2, ncol = 2)
```

This gives:

[image]

This is an easy way to do what you want; there are other ways to do this directly with functions in the **grid** package itself, but they require a little more from the user.