# How do I make a facet/panels of two interaction graphs using lattice in R?

Tags: r, graphics, data-manipulation, lattice

I have this code in R:

```
xyplot(remove_SMO ~ A, groups = C,
   type="a",
   ylab="Remoção de óleo (%)",
   xlab = "pH",
   auto.key = list(space = "right", points = FALSE, lines = TRUE))
```

[image]

And this similar one:

```
xyplot(remove_SMO ~ B, groups = E,
   type="a",
   ylab="Remoção de óleo (%)",
   xlab = "Temperatura",
   auto.key = list(space = "right", points = FALSE, lines = TRUE))
```

[image]

How could I do something like this using `lattice`, grouping these two interaction graphs?

[image]
*The order of the graphics does not matter.

And what good material to learn how to edit graphs developed in `lattice`? Note that the `split` command for multiples plots helps but is not ideal, and there is difference in the positioning of the legend for the pink and blue lines. The "facet_wrap" with `|` is also different, as it greatly changes the aesthetics.

My code for the example.

```
if(!require("FrF2")) install.packages("FrF2") ; library(FrF2)
if(!require("lattice")) install.packages("lattice") ; library(lattice)

plan.person = FrF2(nfactors = 5,
               resolution = 5,
               replications = 2,
               randomize = FALSE,
               factor.names = list(
                 A = c(3, 9),
                 B = c(5, 30),
                 C = c(0.05, 0.5),
                 D = c(50, 350),
                 E = c(100, 200)
               ))

remove_SMO <- c(94.80, 23.40, 99.60, 38.00, 80.20, 27.00, 96.40, 60.00, 99.90, 9.10,
       98.40, 37.10, 99.77, 51.70, 97.40, 58.00, 95.10, 25.00, 99.50, 39.10,
       80.60, 28.00, 96.70, 61.20, 99.70, 10.00, 98.80, 37.40, 99.40, 52.00,
       97.70, 58.40)

plan.atualizado1 = add.response(design = plan.person, response = remove_SMO)

attach(plan.atualizado1)
```

Comment: See that it has the values of y and x (letters), but here I have a new variable. Here I have three variables.

Comment: The solution provided in the link has 3 variables, too, where the third variable is used as `facet` or `group`.

Comment: @hpesoj626, i edited, note that only my Y axis is not varying, and I have two plots with four different factors.

Comment: As to how to get started with `lattice`, see the package's vignette. http://lattice.r-forge.r-project.org/Vignettes/src/lattice-intro/lattice-intro.pdf

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? Start with a minimal sample of your data set. If your data set, say `df` is not that large, paste the output of `dput(df)` into your question.

Comment: I edited again, I inserted a part of my code.

Comment: See solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540129/lattice-multiple-plots-in-one-window

Comment: Thanks for the tip!